# How to implement this common pattern for conditional chaining of observables

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android, rx-java2

```
public Observable<List<A>> buildObservable(final String bId) {
  final Observable<List<B>> bObs = bRepository.getBs(bId);

  return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<List<A>>() {
    @Override
    public void subscribe(final ObservableEmitter<List<A>> subscriber) throws Exception {
      bObs.subscribe(new DefaultObserver<List<B>>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(final List<B> l_B) {
          if (l_B.isEmpty()) {
            subscriber.onNext(new LinkedList<A>());
            subscriber.onComplete();
          } else {
            final List<A> l_A = new LinkedList<A>();

            for (B b : l_B) {
              Observable<A> aObs = aRepository.getbyB(b);
              aObs.subscribe(new DefaultObserver<A>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(A a) {
                  l_A.add(a);
                  if (l_A.size() == l_B.size()) {
                    subscriber.onNext(l_A);
                    subscriber.onComplete();
                  }
                }
              });
            }
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

I find myself having to implement the above pattern over and over again.
I have an observable bObs with a subscriber which triggers a set of observables conditioned on the value from bObs. After they all return, the primary observer returned by the function emits a value.

I feel like there should be a easier way to do this, since this pattern is probably pretty common. Is there some kind of composite operator that helps me take aObs and bObs and construct the top level observable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapting Maxim's proposal above, I was able to find a solution that I am happy with:

```
    return bRepository
    .getBs(bId)
        .defaultIfEmpty(new ArrayList<B>())
    .flatMap(Observable::from)
    .flatMap((b)->{aRepository.getbyB(b);})
    .toList()
    .toObservable();
```

Comment: That's a weird looking observable. Why `.toList().toObservable()`? Wouldn't in be better to do `.toObservable()` after the `defaultifEmpty(...)`?

Comment: well, after defaultIfEmpty it's still an observable. the problem i found when testing this code is that, toList() returns a Single which is not automatically a List and needs to be converted explicitly by toObservable(). Maybe I'm FOS and doing it all wrong, I am an RX newb. The code above does work though.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, avoid creating observables yourself with *`.create()`* as much as possible, because there is almost always a better shorter error proof standard way such as *`.just()` `.empty()` `.from()`* etc.

Secondly, you are totally right that using imperative flow control such as *`if`/`for`* in Rx is just weird because Rx is built upon CPS (Continuation-Passing Style) concept which **is** the flow control in itself.

So in your case it will be something like:

```
bObs.flatMap((b) -> { b.aRepository.getbyB(b).defaultIfEmpty(new ArrayList()); } ).toList()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I take your point about using operators whenever possible. However, i think there are some problems with your code snippet and it does not quite do what i need. The first observable returns a list of B's and for each of them a list of A observables are dispatched and then collected into the final observable. But you brought flatMap and defaultIfEmpty to my attention, so I'm going to modify my question to simplify the code with them.

Comment: Right, just add *.toList()* in the end. Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: not quite, bObs is an Observable<List<B>> not Observable<B>. i think this is almost correct, with some testing i think i found a solution and will put it as a separate answer. thanks !